# Cost to run an Arduino device 24/7, simple maths question

Tags: electricity, cost

I have built an Arduino window automatic closer/opener. When the device is on stand by mode, it draws 12V DC 0.025A.

My quesiton is, how much yearly I need to pay to have this on standby mode?

Would the equation below right?

12V, 0.025 A = 7.2Whour per day. It is then = 365*7.2 = 2628 W hr per year = 2.68kWhour per year.

If electrical cost in NSW Australia 27.56¢/kWh, so it will cost my 2.68*27.56¢ per yer = 72¢ per year.

Above calculation is based on the fact that the 240VAC to 12VDC is at 100% efficiency. I know it is never going to be 100%. Would I assume 90% ok?

So it will cost me 72¢/0.9 = 80.4¢

what do you think?

---

thanks all.

FYI, the reason did measure the AC current was because i was a bit dangerous and complicated to hoook up. but i did it at the end.

i found out at the end that it was drawing 220vac @ 3mAmp, so the cost would be about $1.7 a year.

however, when i open the electonic box. the 5 volt linear regulator was abit warm. and i wanna totoally minimise the heat. sill working on it

Comment: 90% efficiency for the average _switching_ regulator sounds about right. So if 25mA is 90% of the actual power consumed, you can do 0.025/0.9 = 27.78mA. However, as far as I know, Arduino uses a linear regulator (7805?) which won't be that efficient.

Comment: @Lundin The 12V supply is "100% efficicient" as a 12V supply. ie the Arduono uses a linear regulator to convert to 3V3 or 5V BUT this can be ignored if the 12V power is known, as it is.

Comment: _"... is base on the fact that the 240VAC to 12VDC is at 100% efficiency. ... would i assume 90% ok?"_ - Don't assume; look it up in the specifications, and/or measure it! At low power levels (0.3W), I'd expect a significant lower efficiency than 90%.

Comment: Also, if you care about power efficiency, don't feed your Arduino 12V. Look up how linear regulators work to find out why. And research Arduino sleep modes, you can probably cut your Arduino's power consumption by _many_ times.

Comment: Double it, because power supplies are less efficient when you don't use much current. (Even better, actually measure it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks right.

\$ P = VI = 12 \times 0.025 = 0.3 \ \text W \$.

\$ E_{daily} = Pt = 0.3 \times 24 = 7.2 \ \text {Wh} \$.

\$ E_{annual} = 7.2 \times 365 = 2,628 \ \text {Wh} = 2.6 \ \text {kWh}\$

\$ Cost_{Annual} = 2.6 \ \text {kW} \times 27.56\ \text{c/kWh} = \text {AUD }0.72 \$.